# Angular2 async testing issue with ng-inline-svg

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I wrote test for my angular2 component which uses ng-inline-svg module to load my svg file. And after writing actual component it turned out that component works nicely, but test fails. I suspect that test does not wait for svg insertion to finish. Is there some way to fix it? Test which fails:

```
it('Should create new svg element', async(()=>{
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(de.query(By.css('svg'))).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

If i replace 'svg' selector with say 'div' it finds wrapper without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

It's a known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15164

`By.css()` cannot select SVGElement instances.

You should be able to get a reference to the SVG element by using the `DOMElement.querySelector` method.

```ts
it('Should create new svg element', async(()=>{
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const nativeElement = de.nativeElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();        
        expect(nativeElement.querySelector('svg')).toBeTruthy();
    });
}));
```

plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/bgH31O/

---

Original answer:

I don't know the implementation details of the `ng-inline-svg`module, but perhaps the `<svg>` element is inserted into the DOM asynchronously?

If that is the case, you can use [whenStable()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#when-stable):

```ts
it('Should create new svg element', async(()=>{
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(de.query(By.css('svg'))).toBeTruthy();
    });
}));
```

Quoting the docs

> In fact, the whenStable promise resolves when all pending asynchronous activities within this test complete—the definition of "stable."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's being inserted asynchronously since it fetches file with Http.get(), unfortunately whenStable() did not help.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is a known bug of the By.css method.

Comment: I used querySelector() before and it indeed selects svg well if I place it directly in template, it still does not work for svg inserted from file. I added and printed test variable in template, and used `(onSVGInserted)="test=true"` it prints true, but is false in test.

Comment: I actually added interpolation of `test` bool in template, it does not update in karma preview and remains false even though `console.log(this.test);` called onSVGInserted prints true. So test seems to end before it's called.